# How to join the two ends of an expanded shape in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, line-art

The rectangular area shows the broken path that I want to join desperately.

It was originally a picture taken with phone that I imported and traced using the sketched art preset.

The two ends are not paths so when I used join command (Cmd + J), illustrator showed error. I would really appreciate if someone could point out an elegant way of combining the two ends.

[image: AI file]

Comment: You're trying to join points in a closed path, hence the error. Drag the anchor points until it overlaps? Open both ends and join? Add another path on top and Pathfinder > Add? There are many ways to do this, what else have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

select the direct selection tool (A) is shortcut for it, then double click on one of the anchor point to select it and then drag to desired position

Answer (score 0):

Draw a **bridge** shape.

Draw a new shape which overlaps the existing shape and closes the shape.

Select this new shape and the open shape and use the **unite** button on the **Pathfinder Panel** to combine the shapes to one object.

---

Also, you can select the open shape, grab the **Blob Brush** and merely draw a path to close the shape. It *should* auto-merge with the selected shape by default.